# PDF with Laravel is empty

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I'm trying to download a PDF with all my register user email.
The problem is that when i download the PDF, he is empty

I have a controller that create the PDF and with a compact i send all my data to my view.
In my view i display all the data with a foreach

When i print_r the data in my controller, it work, but in my pdf i have nothing.
So i think the problem comes from the compact

```
  public function generatePDF(int $id)

{

    $inscrit = Like::where('type',3)->where('id_event' , $id )->first();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF',  compact('inscrit'));

    return $pdf->download('Inscrits.pdf'); 

} 


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Inscrits</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1> Inscrits pour l'événement : </h1>



</body>

</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <tr>
        <td>



    {{$inscrit->email}}

        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does your view look like?

Comment: I add it in my post

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem. But you have an <td> issue in your view. You are opening it twice and closing it once.

Comment: Complete the table structure, use <table></table> and <tbody>.

Comment: Complete structure is so important in pdf rendering, if it is not complete then pdf will be shown empty or throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Just try to dd your $inscrit variable like dd($inscrit) just to know that you fetch the data.

and you say you want to get all register user but your query is using the first() method. try to use get()

Comment: I was using get() but i switch with first() to see if it works with  it

Comment: what your Like:: facade do ?

Comment: $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF',  $inscrit);

Comment: nice nice hahaha